# how to view/display data from database using different parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could you support me to display data from database using different parameter. Just try to explain I have

```
 => Five=========   **From [] to []** and one another drop down.
 => I need to have accept all drop down values from the user and doing searching and displaying the result on the same page to searching interface. HOW CAN I DO THIS ?
```

PLEASE HELP ME and may I get source code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have a look at stored Procedures - 
call a stored procedure, and pass in the parameters to get the result.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx